# Inverting a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I get this error message:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

Using this code:

```
def invert_networks_dict(person_to_networks):
    """
    (dict of {str: list of str}) -> dict of {str: list of str})
    """

    networks_to_person = []

    for person in person_to_networks:
        networks = person_to_networks[person]
        networks_to_person[networks] = person

        if not (networks in networks_to_person):
            networks_to_person[networks] = person
        else:
            networks_to_person[networks].append[person]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The next error will be on `networks_to_person[networks].append[person]`. Here is a function call needed: `networks_to_person[networks].append(person)`. Notice the `()` instead of `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to 'reverse' dictionary `d` (swap keys and values), with values being list of strings you can:

```
dict((tuple(val), key) for key, val in d.items())
```

However, you can do this only if `d.values` are unique, as keys in new dictionary must be unique.

Explanation:
`dict()` is a built-in that creates dictionary from sequence of pairs `(key, value)`. As with every dictionary, key must be hashable.

Because we want to make values of `d` new keys, we need to transform them to something hashable - in this case this will be tuple. We can create it from any sequence, including lists that are values of `d`, with another builtin: `tuple()`.

So what we need are pairs of keys in values from `d`. We can get them using `d.items()`. We can make this in easy way using list comprehension, additionally wrapping `val` in tuple, to make it hashable, so it can be used as key:

```
[(tuple(val), key) for key, val in d.items())] # that would create list of pairs
```

But if we pass something to function, we don't need to create list, we can pass similar expression as generator comprehension, so our final code looks like:

```
result = dict((tuple(val), key) for key, val in d.items())
```

Comment: does dict represent a general dictionary or the inverted dictionary?

Comment: dict is a built-in constructor, that creates dictionary. You can assign it to something, like `result = dict((tuple(val), key) for key, val in d.items())`

Comment: I add more explanation in a moment

Comment: thank you! i used networks_to_person = dict((v,k) for k in person_to_networks for v in \
                              person_to_networks[k])
    
    return networks_to_person
however, if there is more than one value then only the first value becomes a key, how do i fix this?

Comment: You cannot just 'fix' it. If you are expect to have more than one value, you need to store in dictionary list, like `{ 'my_key' : [1, 2,3 ,4]}`. If that is what you want, you should look at `collections.defaultdict`, but that's another question.
PS. If you like the answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You should have initialized `networks_to_person` as dictionary:

```
networks_to_person = {}
```

Comment: with that change it comes back with TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @user3450897, see glglgl's comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
networks_to_person = []
```

This assigns `networks_to_person` to a list. However, you want it to be a dict:

```
networks_to_person = dict()  # <--
```

You can also use `{}` (empty dict literal), but I prefer `dict()` because it makes your intent more explicit.

---

@glglgl brought up a good point in the comments (which I'll restate here for completeness).

```
networks_to_person[networks].append[person]
```

You want to *call* `append` here, not index it. Therefore, you want:

```
networks_to_person[networks].append(person)
```

---

Lastly, note that you can't have lists as keys to a dictionary. You can convert them to tuples (which can be keys) instead using `tuple()`.

Comment: thank you this is super helpful! where does the tuple() part come in?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that a dict as a `items function`

So instead of that:

```
networks_to_person = {}

for person in person_to_networks:
    networks = person_to_networks[person]
    networks_to_person[networks] = person
```

You can do

```
networks_to_person = {}

for person, networks in person_to_networks.items():
    networks_to_person[networks] = person
```

Which can also be written as:

```
networks_to_person = {networks: person for person, networks in person_to_networks.items()}
```